# How to dynamically add a new row to table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a question for those jQuery guys. I am trying to do in something, but it just does not go. I have a table like this:

`<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>[fields]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`

At the end of each row is an image which is used to add a new row just after it. So, if I click the image, which is in the 3rd row, a new row will be added at the 4th place. Not only that, but that data should be dynamic. What I mean with that is, when the new row is added, the indexes of rows behind that one should be updated. So if I added a row on the 4th place, the row that was 4th before should now be 5th. I think you get the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Row indexes are automatically updated. What do you mean? Can you illustrate your issue with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: How can I retrieve the index of a certain row? Unfortunately, I have no experience with fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.closest()` and `$.after()` to add in the row after the clicked row like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').after('<td>...</td>');
```

To get the value of the current row you can use the following:

```
var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;
```

I have constructed a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UPmPP/) to demonstrate how they can work together to accomplish what you are looking for.

Good luck!